# Loop Through Recordset and count if Within Date Range

Tags: sql

Please note - this is my first post, so I apologize for anything I have missed.

I have a large event table that has a record for each time someone moves within a facility.  What I would like to do, is say if that person was in the facility over the previous 365 days, count them (for each day).  Essentially, I need the Average Daily Population (for everyone in the facility over the previous 365 days).

thank you.

Example Data:

```
PersonID    ArriveDt    LeaveDt Location

1111        1/1/2019    1/3/2019    ABC

1122        1/1/2019    1/5/2019    ABC

1123        1/2/2019    1/6/2019    ABC
```

```
Date        Count       
1/1/2019    2       
1/2/2019    3       
1/3/2019    3       
1/4/2019    2       
1/5/2019    2       
1/6/2019    1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: [Why should I tag my rdbms?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms/388760)

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason to loop as your title suggests.  (depending on rdbms) You should count(*) and group by day.  Then you can do an average.

Comment: The issue is, i would have to count each person (example the first person) for each day in the range.  So, I would want to count that first person 1 time for the first three days. . .sorry, if this is confusing and I am not articulating this well. . .

Answer (score 0):

Create basic calendar table for the last X days:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Calendar') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Calendar;
GO

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = DATEADD(d, -365, GETDATE())
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = GETDATE()

CREATE TABLE #Calendar
(
    [CalendarDate] DATE
)

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
      BEGIN
             INSERT INTO #Calendar
             (
                   CalendarDate
             )
             SELECT
                   @StartDate

             SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, @StartDate)
      END
GO
```

Now CROSS JOIN with Calendar Table to get rows per Person per day they were at a Location and the GROUP BY

```
SELECT 
c.CalendarDate 
,Location 
,COUNT(PersonID) AS PersonCount
FROM (
    SELECT PersonID ,ArriveDt ,LeaveDt ,Location FROM dbo.Table 
) t 
    CROSS JOIN Calendar c 
    WHERE c.CalendarDate BETWEEN t.ArriveDt AND t.LeaveDt

GROUP BY 
    c.CalendarDate 
    ,Location
```

Edit (2019-10-08):
If you're unable to create tables, you can use temp tables instead and do a DROP IF EXISTS. You can run both of these parts in one go on the fly to generate your final report.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information above.  One question, I will have to run this report on a quarterly basis and do not have access to create tables.  For the Calendar table, do you have any suggestions on using the same table for each quarter, i.e. the above will only pull the last 365 days, I will have to run this again in January and will need the previous 365 days from then, without creating the table each quarter, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the intermediate values then really you just need to compute the total man-days and divide.

```
select sum(datediff(day, adjusted_start, adjusted_end) + 1) / 365.0
from T
    cross apply (
        select
            dateadd(day, -365, cast(getdate() as date)),
            dateadd(day,   -1, cast(getdate() as date))
    ) d(range_start, range_end)
    cross apply (
        select
            case when ArriveDt < range_start then range_start else ArriveDt end,
            case when LeaveDt  > range_end   then range_end   else LeaveDt  end
    ) a(adjusted_start, adjusted_end);
```

If not, then come up with a table of dates (from any of numerous sources around the internet) and join from that. An outer join allows for dates with zero census.

```
with dates as (
    select dt from calendar -- exercise for the reader
    where 
            dt >= dateadd(day, -365, cast(getdate() as date)),
        and dt <= dateadd(day,   -1, cast(getdate() as date))
)
select d.dt, count(*)
from dates d left outer join T t
    on d.dt between t.ArriveDt and t.LeaveDt
group by d.dt;
```